# Can you have an external user as a manager in a SharePoint profile?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, userprofilemanager

In the SharePoint user profiles, there is a field to enter in the manager of a user.

[image]

This field is a lookup field, and you can search for internal users to be added to the field as supervisors, but is it at all possible to have external users be assigned as managers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Even though external users have a user profile created for them one, the Manager picker will only resolve Users who are member of the tenant and not external accounts (or Guest Users).

Answer (score 1):

Manager is synchronized from Active Directory so probably you can't

But you can try invite external user to your AAD. Post [HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-users-administrator). In this scenario you should set this accout (haven't tested).